# What to do with the tags 'ussd' and 'remote-ussd-attack'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

Obviously the two are related. But they are also not much frequented. So my question is whether we really need them both. I'd say [remote-ussd-attack](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-ussd-attack) (x2) could easily be referred to using [ussd](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ussd) (x1) and [security](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security), so I'd suggest to make `ussd` the main tag, merging `remote-ussd-attack` into it and make the latter a synonym to the former.

While waiting for your opinions (or quick actions, if approved by our dear moderators), I meanwhile go tagging the other USSD related questions -- so please don't wonder if the mentioned numbers have changed :)

**EDIT:** Yikes, there's also the [dialer-codes](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialer-codes) (x13) tag to be considered. Are USSD codes to be classified as "dialer codes"? Should that be the merge-target instead?

Comment: Skimming [Wikipedia's USSD page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data) (I'm not entirely familiar with this topic) I'm thinking that `dialer-codes` might be better separate, as it seems that there are dialer codes that are not necessarily USSD codes (I think?). Merging the other two into simply `ussd` seems sufficient. Am I off base in that analysis?

Comment: That's in fact a difficult thing. There are 3 closely related terms: "USSD Codes" (`*1nn#`, optionally `*1nn*<parameter>#` are access numbers for simple services. "Supplementary Service Codes" extend them (mailbox services and the like). These both together can be called "GSM Codes". All remaining codes are specific to either the provider, the manufacturer, the system (as e.g. Symbian's S60), or even the device. If you want to dig that deep, that is. For the "common user", these all are just "Secret Codes" :)

Comment: To pick up my last edit in combination with your comment: I explicitly asked whether *USSD codes to be classified as "dialer codes"*, not vice-versa: An apple is a fruit, not necessarily the other way around :) But as said, that's an optional consideration. Main issue still is to merge `ussd` with `remote-ussd-attack` -- optionally giving the latter questions an additional `security` tag. If you can confirm that, I again will care for the "additional tag" so you can concentrate on the merge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about this again, I don't know that a merge is really necessary here. I do think that [remote-ussd-attack](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-ussd-attack) is a little verbose, and that [ussd](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ussd) is sufficient (and can be paired with some other tag like [security](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) if needed. At the same time, since these are such incredibly low-traffic tags, a synonym probably won't even matter.

So for now I've just done some retagging and left [remote-ussd-attack](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-ussd-attack) to die on the vine. If, though some incredible turn of events, a synonym seems necessary later on then we'll cross that bridge.